How to store and source environment variables when they contain semicolon (`;`)
I'm trying to exchange environment variables and restore them quickly between terminals.
I define two functions in my shell (~/.bashrc):
save_env(){
   mkdir -p ~/tmp
   printenv > ~/tmp/env
}

load_env(){
   source ~/tmp/env
}

Both of them work as expected except when there is a semicolon (;) in environment variables, e.g.
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:

When use load_env, get errors like
34:ln=01: command not found
36:mh=00:pi=40: command not found
33:so=01: command not found

How can I fix this?

Use export -p instead of printenv (you still want to make sure the env file is generated and sourced by the same shell and same version thereof and in the same locale). printenv output is not post-processable unless you use -0 as found in some implementations. On Ubuntu, or other Linux-based OSes, see also /proc/self/environ.

; would not be the only problematic character. Any character special in the shell syntax would also be. That includes space, newline |&<>*?[]~#'"\$^() at least.
printenv (a non-standard command) prints name=value followed by a newline character for each environment variable in the environment it receives itself. It prints those names and values raw. It does not intend to produce shell code. In fact, it will also print environment variables whose name cannot be mapped to shell variables.
It will obviously not print shell variables that are not exported to the environment, including array or assoc variables, and of course non-variable shell parameters such as $1, $2, $!, $$...
In the case of the bash shell specifically, it will print the special environment variables that bash uses to export exported functions. Example:
$ env -i $'\n\n=variable with newlines as its name' \
         1=x \
         ++=x \
         bash -c 'f() (:); export -f f; printenv'


=variable with newlines as its name
1=x
++=x
PWD=/tmp
SHLVL=0
BASH_FUNC_f%%=() {  ( : )
}
_=/usr/bin/printenv

To save those of your shell variables that are exported to the environment, you can use export -p (standard, but the output it produces for a given shell can only be used in the same shell (and version thereof, and same OS (libc) and locale)).
For instance, with our example above:
$ env -i $'\n\n=variable with newlines as its name' \
         1=x \
         ++=x \
         bash -c 'f() (:); export -f f; export -p'
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PWD="/tmp"
declare -x SHLVL="1"

Those 3 variables have actually been defined internally by bash itself. OLDPWD is exported, but not set in this case.
Note how bash used declare -x instead of export in the output. That means that when the resulting code is interpreted within a function, the resulting variables will be local to the function. To work around that, you can set the posix option:
$ env -i $'\n\n=variable with newlines at its name' 1=x ++=x bash -c 'f() (:); export -f f; set -o posix; export -p'
export OLDPWD
export PWD="/tmp"
export SHLVL="1"

See however how OLDPWD is exported but not set nor unset, so upon restore, its value will be left unchanged. Same would happen for any variable you export but don't set.
So, your save_env could look like:
save_env() {
  local -
  set -o posix
  mkdir -p ~/tmp && export -p > ~/tmp/env
}

And load_env:
load_env() {
  command . ~/tmp/env
}

(command to avoid exiting the shell upon error if bash is in POSIX mode).
local - (non-standard and copied from the Almquist shell) to make changes to options local to the function need a relatively recent version of bash. With older versions, you can always use a subshell instead of a command group as the body of the save_env function:
save_env() (
  set -o posix
  mkdir -p ~/tmp && export -p > ~/tmp/env
)

Also beware that bash stores the option settings in its SHELLOPTS variable (the long-option variant of the $- parameter). If that variable is exported (which is not a wise thing to do), that posix option will end up included in the value printed by export -p.
To print all variables (not just the exported ones) and their value, you can use set alone, though beware it doesn't include attribute information (like exported, read-only, integer...) and in the case of bash also includes functions. Since that also includes read-only variables, you'll also get errors when sourcing the result.
Like in the Korn shell or zsh, typeset -p can be used to print variable definitions including their type and attributes, but like for export -p when not in posix mode, the output will have things like declare -- var="value" which when sources within a function would create the variable local to the function.
Since version 4.4, bash also has a ${var@A} which expands to the code that could be used to redefine that variable, and that you can use with ${!varname@A} indirection operator, but it gives a bit of a bastard output: it will give var='value' for a scalar variable without attribute, but declare -x var='value' otherwise (with the same issue as above), and for empty arrays or assocs gives declare -a var/declare -A var (since 5.1) instead of declare -a var=()/declare -A var=() (and nothing at all in previous versions) so is pretty useless overall.
With zsh instead of bash, you'd have more control as to which variables you want to select and how they are dumped.
zsh has a special $parameters associative array that maps variable names to their type and attributes.
For instance, print -raC2 -- ${(kv)parameters} to print, keys and values of that assoc raw on 2 Columns (across) outputs something like:
PATH                      scalar-tied-export-special
pipestatus                array-special
HOST                      scalar
jobstates                 association-readonly-hide-hideval-special

To only print the definition of scalar variables that are neither special nor readonly nor hidden, you'd do:
set -o extendedglob
typeset -p -- ${(k)parameters[(R)scalar*~*(special|hide|readonly)*}

If run within a function, it will add a -g option¹ to the generated typeset command lines (except for those variables that are local to the function) which prevent making the variable local if sourced again within a function.

¹ bash's typeset also has a -g option, but that places variables in the outermost scope rather than avoiding making the variable local if not already, so it rather useless.

thanks for this detailed explainatations, i will take it with more study :)
